# Text-To-Speech without browser GUI

Tags: javascript, node.js, background, electron

I have been designing in HTML to create an application that has a GUI. I have created a few scripts for this - particularly one that uses the browser window Speech Synthesis Utterance.

Suddenly, however, the scope of the project has changed and I need to do away with the GUI, but keep the TTS script running as a background process. I'm still quite new to programming, so I tried opening the script with node.js, but it didn't work like that. The utterance is programmed to read a certain xml file. So essentially, all I want to do is to do away with the HTML browser aspect, and keep the javascript. Is this possible? Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could approach this?

I've tried opening the script solely in node.js
I've looked into element.js but it doesn't "seem" to be what I am after.

```
            var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Testing");


            var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            var voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
            speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(function(voice) {
                console.log(voice.name, voice.default ? voice.default : '');
            });

            msg.pitch = 1.1;
            msg.volume = 1;
            msg.rate = 0.85;
            msg.lang = 'en-US';
            msg.voice = voices[1];
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Actual results - Opens a web browser and begins talking (there's a html file)
Expected results I want - No web browser, just talk when the file is opened (maybe?)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, SpeechSynthesisUtterance is a browser-only interface. To use TTS in a server-side Node application, you'll need to install and use a different TTS NPM package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Try Electron with a frameless transparent window.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#transparent-window)

Electron packages up Node and Chromium for desktop applications.

I just tried this out and it worked for me:

```
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
# Go into the repository
cd electron-quick-start
# Install dependencies
npm install
```

Edit renderer.js and insert your code above.

Edit the window in main.js

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      frame: false,
      transparent: true,
      webPreferences: {
         preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
      }
  })
```

Then make everything blank in index.html

Comment: Khobalt, you're the best. Thank you, this works perfectly. I'll need to fiddle with a few things, but overall this is going to work really well. (if my score was a little higher I would up rank this solution).